# Settings required for Audiokit engine

Tags: audiokit

I'm trying to run the tuner part of the cookbook so as to use it as a starter for another project.
The cookbook version works well but my project must be missing a setting somewhere.

The controller fails with
throwing -10878

I've set up the following:

- a plist with "Privacy - Microphone Usage Description" set
- an entitlements file with audio input set to yes

It looks like it should work and the error is not very descriptive because it's doing :

```
 guard let device = engine.inputDevice else { fatalError() }
```

So It gives Fatal error when it fails.

What should I try next? to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Add "Privacy - Microphone Usage Description" permission to your info.plist. You can see an example of how it is added in the Cookbook app. Select your target, then the info tab to add the row. [image: Privacy - Microphone Usage Description]

Edit: Oh sorry you already tried adding this to the plist. throwing -10878 is a known issue that is possibly an Apple related issue, not an AudioKit one. That warning shows up in the Cookbook built too but it doesn't result in a crash or the app not building.